Recover access to USB external encrypted hard disk
I just switched from Ubuntu 20.04 to Ubuntu 24.04.
In 2021, I bought an USB external hard disk and encrypted it.
I flagged "save forever" password so when I needed some files, it will not ask.
This was a breeze, but having the ease of not having to type the password every single time, it made me forgot it!!
Unfortunately during the OS reinstall, I forgot I had this external hard disk and I wiped Ubuntu 20.04 in favor of the newer 24.04.
Now I desperately need the files in that hard disk.
I remember the password to be a combination of some words, but I don't remember their order/combination.
Is there something to automate the construction of the password by these smaller words and trying to decrypt it?
For example I know for sure that the password is the union of some substring, say AAA, BBB, CCC, or DDD.
I don't remember if it may be AAABBBCCCDDD or DDDDAAACCCBBBB or BBBAAA.
Thanks!

any help? please
